# How to wire a digital LED voltmeter in line with an illuminated rocker switch so the switch light is on and the meter displays the actual voltage

Tags: led, voltage-measurement

12v power supply to put output signal on a 7 way trailor connecter.How to wire the LED voltmeter in series with an illuminated rocker switch,so when the switch is turned on,and the light is lit,the volt meter shows read out of the actual measured voltage.

Comment: Put the positive terminal of the meter on the positive output terminal of the switch.  Put the negative terminal of the meter on the negative output terminal of the switch.

Comment: Thankyou very much!

Answer (score 2):

You don't wire a voltmeter in series with the load. Instead you wire it in parallel with the load because you're trying to measure the voltage across the load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHPSEH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A voltmeter is wired across the load. An ammeter is wired in series with the load.*